# Exercise about convex function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am stuck on the second part of this exercise.

> Find the values of $\rho \in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = x + e^{\rho\vert x\vert}$ is convex in $\mathbb{R}$. (Hint: for $\rho < 0$ obtain a contradiction of convexity using $f(\pm \rho)$ and $f(0)$).

**What I've done**

So first of all I analysed the case $\rho \geq 0$.

For $\rho = 0$ I simply have $f(x) = x+1$ which is convex on $\mathbb{R}$, done.

For $\rho > 0$ I said $f(x) = x + e^{\rho\vert x\vert}$ can be thought as a sum of conve functions, which will then be convex.
$x$ is convex, done.

$e^{\rho\vert x \vert}$ is the composition between $e^{\rho x}$ and $\vert x \vert$.
The first one is convex in $\mathbb{R}$ but it's also increasing. The second one is just convex.

Hence, I used the fact that if $F$ is convex and increasing and $G$ is convex, then $F\circ G$ is convex.

This means $e^{\rho x }\circ \vert x \vert = e^{\rho \vert x \vert}$ is convex.

Finally, sum of convex in thence convex.

**Stuck part**

I don't understand the hint for $\rho < 0$.
How could I proceed?

Answer (score 5):

Let $\rho < 0$. Then $f(0) = 1, f(\rho) = \rho + e^{-\rho^2}$ and $f(-\rho) = -\rho + e^{-\rho^2}$.

If $f$ is convex, then $f\left( \dfrac{\rho + (-\rho)}{2} \right) \leq \dfrac{f(\rho) + f(-\rho)}{2} \implies 1 \leq e^{-\rho^2} < 1$, resulting in a contradiction. Hence, $f$ is not convex for any $\rho < 0$.